# iframe height not taken into account by IE8

Tags: css, iframe, internet-explorer-8, height, widget

I'm building a dummy widget for a iGoogle/Netvibes like portal. This is a "Google Maps" widget, as it only renders a map centered on a specific location.

The widget looks good in all browsers but IE8, in which the height I specify to the `<div>` that contains the map is not taken into account.

Here's the interesting part of the code:

```
<body onload="initialize()" >

<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; width: 100%;"></div>

</body>
```

I have no control on the portal, so the only thing I can modify is the widget itself. I also tried to set the height for the `<body>`, but same thing.

Any idea on why it's not working in IE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the page you're calling with the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframes = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for(var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i ++)
    {
        if(iframes[i].src == window.location)
        {
            iframes[i].style.height = '400px';
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you are on 2 different domains, this isn't possible, and unfortunately there is no other way when supplying the `<iframe>` directly to the end-user. The best solution would be to instead give the user a script tag that generates the `<iframe>` tag using a `document.write()`

Example script tag to give to your client:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/widget-getter.js?client=[clientid]&amp;widget=[widgetid]"></script>
```

Contents of the script that the above tag would call:

```
document.write('<iframe height="400px" src="http://www.example.com/widget.html"></iframe>');
```

Comment: Yeah that would surely work, but this part of the code is generated by the portal for each widget, and as I said, I can't modify that :/

So there's no way for me to modify the iframe element

But thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi orokusaki and thanks for your time. 
Unfortunately, as the iframe and the portal aren't located under the same domain, I can't modify elements such as window.parent.*** - for cross-domain security reasons.

Comment: So are you telling me there is no way to have it properly rendered in IE8? Isn't there a known issue about iframe height and IE? Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: @Pedro - iframe is intrinsically limited in many ways, but the real problem comes from not having access to the page's source (to add the `height="400px"`, etc. Did you check my latest answer? You can do a `document.write()` to put the iframe in and hand your clients a `<script>` tag instead of handing them the actual `<iframe>`. This is what Google does with AdSense.

Comment: That works!
So I ended up specifying a fixed height for the iframe (400px), and a height of 100% for the div that contains the map.
Not conventional, but effective, thanks orokusaki-sama :)

Comment: @Pedro no problemo, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the height attribute of the iframe tag?

Comment: I wish I could, but the iframe is generated by the portal (an iframe is generated for each widget), and I can't modify that :/